# I just found many facebook entries on my registry?

Tags: windows, audit, facebook

I don't have a Facebook account but I was messing with my registry deleting old stuff and I found a bunch of Facebook keys and folders.
Facebook is notorious for being a tool for spy agencies and has poor privacy. So I'm concerned about the entries.

How I can figure out why and what these entries are doing on my system, and why its coming back when I delete them?

[image: Entries]

That was not the only one, but I already deleted the others. For now it hasn't come back, yet... Still I think it's very weird. I did Google it and couldn't find anything about Facebook creating entries on registry or why, even when you don't have Facebook at all. Also, my OS is Windows 7.

Comment: "Facebook is notorious for being a tool for spy agencies..." ok maybe so but I doubt they want to be; "...and has poor privacy." Since when? Last time I checked I could control every piece of content I've ever out on it to the finest degree of detail. If you don't have an account, how have you come up with that claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they keep coming back, it means that you have some software running checks on them. You should take some tool to analyze the running processes on your machine.

Use [**Process Explorer**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to look at the current running processes (so that you can find out which one is recreating the reported keys and [**Autoruns**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to check the list of programs initiated automatically at startup (search if the above process is configured to startup with windows, or if you have something suspicious installed).

Only by researching the name of the binary you will be able to discover what it does and figure if it should be there or not.

A common source of issues like this is the installation of software that comes bundled with adwares (the ones that have to be unchecked during the "*next->next->finish*" sequence).

Comment: +1, these are some great ideas to start out. The OP should keep in mind that if the registry is being modified, he may be dealing with a rootkit, which might hide the processes and files.